# Converting a string into decimal given the number of decimals

Tags: ruby

is there a clever way to obtain

```
result == 22.000000000000000000
```

by starting with these values?

```
str = "22000000000000000000"
decimals = 18
```

another example:

```
str = "4500000000001"
decimals = 8
result == 45000.00000001
```

Comment: Is `decimals` supposed to represent how many zeros there are after the period?

Comment: yes, my bad, I wrote `8` instead of `18` sorry ;(

Comment: What is your expected result – a `Float` or a `BigDecimal` or something else?

Comment: a Float I guess should be ok!

Comment: would it truncate at N or round?

Comment: I guess converting the string to a number and dividing it by `10 ** decimals` is not clever enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking all the comments above that would be:

```
"%0.#{decimals}f" % (str.to_f / 10 ** decimals)
```

But is it clever? Probably not... and it can produce incorrect results, e.g. with `"22000000000000000001"` it would result in `"22.000000000000000000"`, although it does produce the expected results with the example values in the original question.

Here's another option that produces the exact same result as above but is more compact and will always produce the expected result:

```
str.insert(-decimals - 1, ".")
```

You can convert both of these to float with `.to_f` but the result will always be `22.0` and not the intended value of the original question.

Comment: Technically this returns a string when in the question a float was desired, though the float does have trailing zeroes which aren't shown normally.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not knowledgeable enough in Ruby to know how to display more trailing zeroes with a float. If anyone knows I'll gladly update the answer.

Comment: You can't with a regular float, they're suppressed on display. The original question is confused as to if it wants a formatted string representation or an actual float value, so just making a note here about that ambiguity.

Comment: Ok, I've added that information to the question and added another option to achieve the same result.

Comment: I was going to add a string-based answer using `insert` as a sarcastic response, but now that I see your answer it's actually not that bad an idea.

Comment: With `str = "22000000000000000001"` your two ways give different results.

Comment: Well spotted. I've edited the question with that in mind.

Comment: I don't see how you'd get `"0.000000000000000022"`. You should get `"22.000000000000000000"` instead, losing the `1`. Btw, you could use `str.insert(~decimals, ".")`.

Comment: That also took me by surprise. Clearly I messed something up when testing. I've fixed the return value in that case. Your option seems to be more clevery :) You can add that as an answer. Maybe it will be enough to be accepted as the correct answer.